# Spring controller not showing the relevent view

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I've got the following spring controller class.

```
@Controller
public class LayoutController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/layout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ShowLayout(){
        return "redirect:/views/layout.html";
    }
}
```

This is my common-config xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

        <!--  COMMON CONFIGURATIONS -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <tx:annotation-driven/> 

        <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".html" />

        <!-- Annotations based Configuration -->
        <context:annotation-config />

        <mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />

        <!-- Components Auto-Detection (Backend) -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.jkcs.touchpos" use-default-filters="false" >
            <!-- Types annotated by Spring Managed, Controller and Transactional, or by an annotation that itself is 
            annotated by SpringManaged, Controller, Transactional -->
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.jkcs.touchpos.platform.annotations.SpringManaged"/>
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional"/>
        </context:component-scan>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

</beans>
```

This is my mvc-config xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
</beans>
```

This is my web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TouchPOS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

finally the dispatcher servlet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!--  SPECIFIC CONFIGURATIONS -->
    <import resource="springConfigurations/common-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="springConfigurations/mvc-config.xml"/>

</beans>
```

When I run this web app on a jetty server, and I use the following URL to get the layout.
But the server throws a 404 error. please help me to identify the wrong thing I'm doing?

```
http://localhost:8080/TouchPOSApplicatio/layout
```

Update : The web page elements show properly but with no CSS. And the console printed the following error.

```
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/style/style.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/style/jquery.custom-scrollbar.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/jquery.colorbox.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/functions.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/dragscrollable.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/jquery-ui.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/style/colorbox.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/jquery.colorbox.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/functions.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 2:17:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/js/dragscrollable.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `TouchPOSApplicatio` is just a typo in the question? I'm strugglig to understand your pattern here. You have mapped static resources to `/WEB-INF/views`, which is not accesible from the browser, so I don't think that'll work. Try putting it into a regular webapp folder instead, like `static` (at the same level as `WEB-INF`). Then change your config to:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static"/>
```

and then you can verify that it can be accessed by typing `http://localhost:8080/TouchPOSApplication/static/layout.html`. If that works, then you have configured the static resources correctly.

**Edit**

If you have css resources also, make sure to add the folder with those resources also as a mvc:resource.

Comment: Well that works fine! :) thankyou for the reply! The web page elements are displayed but the CSS is not applied!

Comment: Make sure your css'es are accessible as well. And make sure you use the context path when referring to them if you're not using relative urls.

Comment: You are a genius man! :) thank you for giving me the help! I defined the resources and it worked fine! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is mapped to `@RequestMapping(value = "/layout", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, and your servlet mapping is `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`, so the URL should be `http://localhost:8080/layout`.

Besides, as NilsH already said, your controller redirect to a file that the browser can not see directly. It should be exposed as a static file.